# Maxent in R Error: Bias grid cannot be used with SWD-format background

Tags: r, maxent

I get this error when running;

```
me_1 <- maxent(pred, occ, args='biasfile=bias')

Error: Bias grid cannot be used with SWD-format background
```

where 'pred' is a raster stack, 'occ' is a csv file of lat/lon, and 'bias' is a raster.  The model runs fine without the 'args'.  The error suggests that it thinks I'm using a SWD (species-with-data) file but I'm not. Have checked the str() on each input file.  I've updated everything (R, RStudio, dismo, maxent.jar).  Running on Windows 10. I see others have had this problem on the Maxent user group, but no solutions.  Any help appreciated.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To update - it may be that dismo does not have biasfile implemented.  However a workaround can be found here 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/Maxent/kUZTkSiDxbU/i_-cDR4aN8MJ